# A word meaning sth I extremely hate

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, british-english

Could the word chastise be used to describe something I extremely hate?

Example:

> I chastise football. (I hate football immensely).

If chastise does not work, could you please provide an alternative?

Dictionary examples weren't strong enough. I was looking for a much stronger hate. Googling *"extreme hate"* brought some words which I googled and didn't see they are used too much. The words that I thought were good:

> - **Abhor**: disgusted (I don't know how to use in the right context to so it's understandable).
> - **Despise**: Not strong enough. Translated to *hate* or to express being far from.

Comment: "to chastise " means to punish or to criticize.  So you could not use it in the sense of "I hate football".  "I chastise football" doesn't quite work but "He spent his career chastising footballers for their high pay" might

Comment: As Vorsprung said, "chastise" doesn't mean "to hate" but "to scold, criticize" (perhaps out of hate, but not necessarily). Some other options for "to hate" that you haven't listed and may not have found in your research include _detest_, _loathe_, and _scorn_.

Comment: @vanderpn I never heard them or saw them being used in a sentence, This is why I asked. To get the help in finding the suitable word to be put in context. 
@Hank sorry for the whole mess. I realize how hard it is, trust me I spend many hours a day on `SO` helping others and I know how it is.

Comment: @TonyTannous The reason we require demonstrated research is to ensure it's not a general reference question pursuant to the guidelines in [Are Some Questions Too Simple](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/). No screenshots are necessary, but demonstration of research is, so we do not try to replicate your efforts, which would not be very useful to you. All we request is a properly cited quotation of what you examined which is mostly a matter of using copy/paste, and the reasons you dismissed it to clarify the nature of the question.

Comment: I have voted to reopen because OP showed the effort (research) put in prior to asking.

Comment: For your example, *despise* would work very well.  You weren't sure how to use *abhor*.  Example: I abhor the sound of keys being jangled.  (They irritate my senses.)  I try to avoid environments where this might occur. // Make sure when you're looking up words in dictionaries, that you look carefully at the example sentences.  They can be quite helpful.

Comment: @aparente001 thanks for the comment. I appreciate it. I used abhor :).

Comment: @aparente001 it will not be reopened. Its personal more than the content of the question. I don't think this question after being edited deserved a downvote yet it got the downvote.. and even worse was flagged to be closed. Bitter people what can I do... but thanks god there are also people like you willing to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that Abhor and Loathe are the strongest words to denote hatred of something. And you would use them to replace the word "hate".

> I **hate** football.
>   I **abhor** football.
>   I **loathe** football.

If you want to use a word as a noun rather than a verb, you could say that something is an Abomination.

> Football is an **abomination**.

Comment: Also, although not common, [_abominate_](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abominate) can be used as a transitive verb meaning "to hate something," as in "I abominate football." However, AntonH's suggestions will be more likely to register with your audience.

Comment: Also "execrate", although it's not really commonly used anymore.

Comment: I like this answer and I would note that the suggestion of calling something an abomination goes a nice additional step that might be the OP's true but unexpressed desire to express.  He might want to say more than that he personally has an intense distaste but go a step farther and criticise the sport itself on it's merits.  "I hate writing papers with footnotes" might allow room for you to believe that you're glad that other people, (professors, experts) write papers with footnotes.